# Indexing through Multiline Textbox

Tags: arrays, vba, textbox

I am trying to figure out how to index through a string populated using a multiline textbox. I need to go through each line of the textbox to determine the number of characters in each line.

So far my code pulls the text from the textbox and splits it. The number of lines can be anywhere from 2 to 8. I'm not sure how to index through the string to find size and length of the array/text. I tried using Ubound to get the number of lines and Len to get the length of each line, but can't seem to get them to work.

```
 Dim Marking As String
 Dim Lines As String 
 Dim LineCount As Integer
 Dim LineWidthTemp as Integer
 Dim LineWidth as Integer
 Dim LineIndex as Integer

 Marking = UserForm1.Stencil.Text
 Lines = Split(Marking, vbCrLf)
 LineCount = UBound(Lines()) + 1

 For Lines(1) To Lines(LineCount)
    LineWidthTemp = Len(LineIndex)
    If LineWidthTemp > LineWidth Then
    LineWidth = LineWidthTemp
    Else
 Next
```

The end result should be able to use the array length to index through all lines to determine all of their character lengths and save the highest amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
Dim l As Variant, maxLen As Long

For Each l In Split(Me.Stencil.Text, vbCrLf)
    Debug.Print l, Len(l)
    If Len(l) > maxLen Then maxLen = Len(l)
Next l
```